# Scrolling without mouse in jscrollpane/jquery

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have managed to get jscrollpane up & running, but I have a few issues left. I've done a lot of testing, but failed to solve this errors:

If I want to scroll with the arrow keys or page up/down, the whole site moves, not only the div. I've come to manage that with just preventing these keys

```
$(window).keypress(function(evt) {
        switch(evt.keyCode) {

        case 33:
        case 34:
        case 38:
        case 40:
            evt.preventDefault();
            break;
        }


 });
```

This is obviously a workaround. How can I fix this?

Second is, that I failed with really any implementation of Android/iPhone/iPad Support for jScrollpane. I've really tried a lot. Many versions where outdatet (but I even failed with using older versions of jScrollpane).

Can someone please give a review of up-to-date options to implement this!

I really appreciate any help, as I'm at my wits end!

Answer (score 0):

To scroll with the arrow keys (and page up and page down) you need to first focus the scroll pane by clicking on it. This is the same behaviour as native scroll areas (with overflow: auto). If you are seeing different behaviour make sure you have the latest version of jScrollPane [ http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ ].

Again, touchscreen support is included in the latest version of jScrollPane and AFAIK is working well. If you are still having problems you'll need to send a link to a page displaying the problems so we can help debug.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I checked in the author's homepage of jScrollPane version 1, the pageup and pagedown keys are indeed not functioning (I use firefox), even with Focus.

Example can be seen Here: 
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/examples.html

One can indeed click in the middle of any of the 5 panes to get focus, and only in "#pane5 (normal OS provided)" do the Pageup Pagedown key work.

Same goes to Ctrl-Home and Ctrl-End combination.

In version 2 this problem was fixed: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/